# STL way of creating/filling std::set from std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdvector, stdset

I want to create and fill a `set` from the contents of a member variable of each entry of a `vector`. This is what I am doing:

```
struct S { int i; };

int main()
{
    std::vector<S*> structPtrs;

    // code to fill the above vector

    // create set from the above vector
    std::set<int> setInts;
    for (auto it = structPtrs.begin(); it != structPtrs.end(); ++it)
    {
        setInts.insert((*it)->i);
    }
}
```

Is there an STL way to do it? Or via any available method(s) in `<algorithm>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one other way you can do this. If you add conversion operator to `int` to your struct you can just use range constructor directly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct test {int i; operator int() {return i;}};

int main() {
    vector<test> v;
        v.push_back(test{433});
        v.push_back(test{533});
        set<int> s(v.begin(), v.end());
        cout << *(++s.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

https://www.ideone.com/qJwtwc

Comment: Thank you for formatting the code @RHertel much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You can always apply [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) from the range defined by the vector onto the "range" defined by an [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter):

```
transform(begin(structPtrs), end(structPtrs),
          inserter(setInts, end(setInts)), [] (S* s) {
  return s->i;
});
```

That should be more than enough use of the standard library.

---

If you are willing to look beyond the standard library, there is also the option of using something like [`boost::transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html), which will allow you to move the range transformation into the set's initialization:

```
auto transfomer = [](S* s) { return s->i; };
std::set<int> setInts(
  boost::make_transform_iterator(begin(structPtrs), transfomer),
  boost::make_transform_iterator(end(structPtrs), transfomer)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `std::transform` with an appropriate lambda and an insert iterator:

```
std::transform(structPtrs.begin(), structPtrs.end(), std::inserter(setInts, setInts.end()),
    [](S* sp) { return sp->i; });
```

But personally, I find a simple range for loop to be much easier to follow:

```
for (S* sp : structPtrs)
    setInts.insert(sp->i);
```